# using ref inside chapter or section in lualatex

Tags: hyperref

As stated in the original title of the thread, I would like to use a reference number inside a section name.

Actually, it is to refer using the structure like

```
\section{Data related to Figure~\ref{fig:XY}}
```

The MWE for what I want is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}\label{c:First}
\chapter{I want to use ref~\ref{c:First} here }\label{c:Second}
\section{Dummy section}
\newpage
\section{Dummy section in new page}
\end{document}
```

I tried to run such file into LuaLaTeX several times, since I am using it for my actual project. The related line in log output is

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `C:FIRST' on page 4 undefined on input line 16.
```

The PDF file is generated, but the chapter name in page 4 becomes

```
CHAPTER 2. I WANT TO USE REF ?? HERE
```

I tried to find a possible duplicate, but I didn't find. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `\MakeUppercase`, that is used for the page headers, also converts the argument of `\ref`. A protected macro could be defined to prevent this:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\refcfirst}{\ref*{c:First}}
...
\chapter{I want to use ref~\refcfirst\ here}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It solved my issue. Just to complement, even if is sounds obvious (well, for me it wasn't at first): the robust declaration must be done before begin document.